# Set QTtableWidget Header color using QT Designer

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Let me start by saying I am new to programming in general but just started to use PYQt6 and QT Designer to build my user interface. I have a QTableWidget that consists of 180 columns. I have filters that allow me to hide columns based off "Groupings". I want to take it a step further and set the headers of all the "Groupings" to a specific color so when scrolling through the table its easier to separate each “Grouping”.

Example:
Columns 0 – 10 are Group1 – Make headers for Columns 0 – 10  Blue
Columns 11 – 20 are Group2 – Make headers Columns 11 – 20  Red
I would like to use QT Designer if possible since I created my table there and have all the column header text set.

I have tried something like this:

```
item1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()   
item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,item1)type here
```

but when I do that it overwrites the current column header text and doesn’t actually change the color.
I don’t mind doing it in code but want to utilize the UI file created by QT Designer for the Header text if possible.

I found this example below and it works until I try to use it in my app. So I feel like it is not specifically a windows thing. Its a me not knowing what I am doing thing.

```py
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,initials=None):
        QtWidgets.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5,3,self)
        self.table.move(30,30)
        self.table.resize(400,300)

        item1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('red')
        item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,item1)

        item2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("green")
        item2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1,item2)

        item3 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('blue')
        item3.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2,item3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion')) # won't work on windows style.
    Frame = MyFrame(None)
    Frame.resize(500,400)
    Frame.show()
    app.exec()
```

is setting the header text to "Red" How would I change it so it wont overwrite my header text?

Comment: Instead of replacing the item, you should just set the background of the existing one: get the header item with [`horizontalHeaderItem(column)`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#horizontalHeaderItem) and use `setBackground()` on that. But note that not all styles implement the color features of headers, and in that case they are completely ignored. What OS are you using? What is the output of `print(QApplication.style().objectName())`? Also, note that with item models that large, if you need "filtering", it would probably be better to implement a custom model with a standard QTableView.

Comment: In any case, Qt Designer allows to set header backgrounds: just double click the table widget, select the section in the "Columns" tab, click the "Properties <<" button, then scroll to the "background" section and set the custom color for that specific section. Note that if you see the background in Designer but not in your program, you should start by checking the UI previews in the "Form>Preview in" menu. As said above, it's possible that the default style of your OS doesn't consider the background role, meaning that you need to create a QHeaderView subclass and implement its `paintSection`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did try setting the background color via the table widget properties and it highlights the column name in the properties window but doesn't show up in the preview or the actual app. I am using WIndows 10. I will try again with horizontalHeaderItem(column) but it didnt seem to recognize the setBackground() when I tried.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do more tests as I don't use Windows. But, if the default windows style doesn't respect the `BackgroundRole` of the item (which is what `setBackground()` sets for the header data), then the only remaining option is to set a custom subclass of QHeaderView and override its `paintSection()`. It *may* be enough to just use `qp.fillRect(rect)` with the color returned from the model's `headerData()` background role and then call the base implementation with `super().paintSection(painter, rect, index)`, but I'm not sure: the style may still paint over it.

Comment: Added some example code I found that I can run and seems to work fine. Not sure how to bring it into my app though.

Comment: I got it. needed to add this line: app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion')) I guess default windows style doesn't work

Comment: Note that there is also the overloaded [`setStyle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#setStyle-1) which doesn't need the QStyleFactory constructor: just do `app.setStyle('fusion')`. Also, using the fusion style on that view will completely override the style for any of its children, so that may not be a good choice. Please consider setting a custom QHeaderView as written above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I will try what you suggested. Im just glad something is possible.